# How to generate a random String of 0's and 1's that is 8 digits long in one line of code?

Tags: java

```
public class Main {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                // generate a random String of 0's and 1's that is 8 digits long
                System.out.println("Print the string of 0's and 1's");
        }
    }
```

> I want to do it in just one, and only one line of code.

Comment: But why? Why only one line of code?

Comment: Because the challenge for my project is to write the least amount of code possible. It would be easy to create a method that does it for me, but I wanna do it in one, and only one line of code. Nothing has to do with the efficiency.

Comment: Then what's your try so far?

Comment: `System.out.println(Stream.generate(() -> Integer.toString((int) (Math.random() * 2))).limit(8).collect(Collectors.joining()));`

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Or `new Random().ints(8, 0, 2)`

Answer (score 2):

In case you don't want to include binary numbers starting with 0 like '00001010' and you only want to represent binary number that starts with 1 then you 'play' between 128 and 255, cause the 10000000 = 128 in decimal and 11111111 = 255 in that case you will need to do something like this:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(128 + (int) (127 * Math.random())));
```

The Math.random() gives you a number bewteen 0.0 and 1.0 so 127 * Math.random will give you a random value between [0,127] and because we want to start our binary number with '1' then for sure the number must be bigger that 128 = 10000000.

In case you want to include all the number from 0 to 255 here is what you could do :

```
System.out.println(String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString((int) (255 * Math.random()))).replace(' ', '0'));
```

Comment: I think leading zero counts also

Comment: Indeed it is an assignment. This is perfect, but why did you use the numbers 128 and 127? And, will this generate a string that is longer than 8 digits ? The reason why I am asking is because it needs to be 8 digits long no less and no more.

Comment: For 0 to 255, you may also use the way you used in your first case, i.e., `Integer.toBinaryString(256 + (int) (Math.random() * 255)).substring(1, 8);`

Comment: @MohammadMahjoub you need to change 128 and 127 to a binary number and you'll know the answer.

Comment: @Alex that's not true. `256 + (int) (Math.random() * 255)` will give you more than 8 digits. If it has to be 8 and only 8 you will need to stay between 0 and  255.

Comment: @JKostikiadis I just added substring at the back.

Comment: @Alex In that case you are also correct. Mohammad Mahjoub the first method will give you all the binary numbers between 128 and 255 which are all 8 bits in length. The second case will give you all the numbers between 0 and 255 also 8 bits in length.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with an `IntStream`. Its not a great solution because it instantiates several `Random` objects, but its one line of code:

```
IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 8).forEach(x->System.out.print(new Random().nextInt(2)));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [RandomStringUtils](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/RandomStringUtils.html#random-int-char...-) and specify which characters you need.

```
System.out.println(RandomStringUtils.random(8, '0', '1'));
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one line, though it's definitely not the most readable way of doing this. Most things are possible in one line, but not easy to debug or understand at a glance. This also isn't the fastest way, but you said you didn't care about efficiency.

```
String random8Bits = new Random().ints(8, 0, 2).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

How it works:

```
new Random()
// creates a random number generator
.ints(8, 0, 2)
// returns an IntStream containing 8 random numbers between 0 (inclusive) and 2 (exclusive).
.mapToObj(Integer::toString)
// converts each int in the stream to its string representation
.collect(Collectors.joining())
// joins the strings
```

For further information, see [`Random.ints(long, int, int)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#ints-long-int-int-), [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) and [`Collectors.joining()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--).

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the toBinaryString method of Class Integer. Then pass it a new random it wich you short to a byte (8 bits) by applying a & 0xff.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(new Random().nextInt() & (0xff)));
    }
}
```

Comment: What does "0xff" mean?

Answer (score 0):

We can randomly choose a number that has 8 bits in it's representation and print it:

```
    int n = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(128, 256);
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(n));
```

we want the number to be bigger than 127 because otherwise we won't have 8 bits (for the same reason we want it to be smaller than 256).

Answer (score 0):

Just another solution:

```
String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(new Random().nextInt() & 0xFF)).replace(' ', '0')
```

No streams, single `Random`, but with `String` manipulations...

Answer (score 0):

Here's another "solution":

```
System.out.println((Integer.toBinaryString(
    new Random().nextInt()) + "00000000").substring(0, 8));
```

... except that it is slightly biased.  Line wrapped for readability!

Also, note that according to a literal interpretation:

```
{ int tmp = new Random().nextInt(); /* add more statements here */ }
```

is one line of code.  And it is even one Java statement :-).

---

*UPDATE*: here's another version with no bias:

```
System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(
    new Random().nextInt() | 0x80000000).substring(24));
```

Forcing the sign bit to be 1 means that we won't have to worry about whether the leading zeros are there or not.